# How to leave promiscuous mode in dnscap?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, pcap

How to leave promiscuous mode in dnscap?

`dnscap -a` makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
dnscap -p
```

Or is that what you meant by -a ?